# Examples of different roots (and different meanings) coming to be spelled the same

Tags: etymology, vocabulary, list-request

Apparently the two opposite meanings of *to cleave* have different roots: the *to adhere* meaning comes from one old English root (*clifian*) and the *to cut* meaning comes from a different old English word (*cleofan*). [According to this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_auto-antonyms_in_English#C)

Similarly, in the expressions *to run the gauntlet* and *to throw down the gauntlet*, the word *gauntlets* in question has quite different provenances: in the fist case it is from an old Norse word for a passage (if my memory serves), while in the second case it is from the French *gant* (glove).

What other examples of this fascinating phenomenon do you know of?

Comment: Not many people say "cleave" or "run the gauntlet" or "throw down the gauntlet" these days.

Comment: @Shinto Sherlock - Usage may depend upon geographical location or the English language entertainment genres one enjoys. Also, the above are phrases which one *is* likely to encounter when reading literature or watching movies or television shows set in certain parts of Europe centuries ago. In the US, we have a television show called "Merlin", set in Medieval Camelot, in which one regularly hears the phrases "run the gauntlet" or "throw down the gauntlet".

Comment: @ssaki: regularly?

Comment: @Shinto Sherlock I don't see how these words' rarity is at all relevant

Comment: @Seamus: relevant to what?

Comment: @Shinto Sherlock I'm trying to work out what you meant by your first comment. I don't see how it's relevant to the question I asked.

Comment: @Seamus: If my comment said something like "it's nice weather today, isn't it?" then I would understand why you thought the comment was not relevant, but since the comment is about the words in your question I believe it is relevant to this discussion.

Comment: @Shinto the question is about history of spellings, whereas your comment is about diversity of usage, so Seamus’s confusion seems apt to me. Please try to make the tone of your comments more kind and less cutting.

Comment: @nohat: What on earth are you talking about? I can't see anything unkind or cutting in any of the above comments.

Comment: @Ex-user: indeed, I don't see anything unkind or cutting, but neither do I see the relevance of your first comment or indeed the relevance of the lack of current usage. My response to that first comment would have been "cool story, bro". In fact a better comment would have been to point out that @Seamus used the plural phenomena when he should have used the singular phenomenon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [bear](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=bear)
- [lead](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=lead)
- [row](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=row)
- [yard](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1275/etymology-of-yard)
- ...

More examples can be found on the [list of English homographs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_homographs) over at Wikipedia.

And then there are the [capitonyms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitonym) (august/August, march/March, polish/Polish).